# How to extract a entire row, based on a single key word with first occurrence from a csv or excel file?

Tags: shell, parsing, awk, sed

I would like to extract a row from a excel sheet based on a multiple key words (strings)with single occurence. 
So I have got the linux command like this,

```
grep -e "keyword" | head -1
awk '/keyword/ { print; exit; }' ./filename
```

It works for single key word, when I intended to do the same for multiple strings, I have got a linux command like this,

```
sed -n -e '/keyword1/p;/keyword2/p;/keyword2/p' ./file'
sed -n -E -e '/(keyword1|keyword2|keyword3)/p' ./file
grep -E -e '(keyword1|keyword2|keyword3)' ./file
```

But, these commands extracts all the keywords (the same keyword have more than 50 to 60 redundant occurrence in the excel/csv file) but not stops the first occurrence.
Please help me to solve this problem. I have to extract the multiple strings with first occurrence.

Comment: what does this have to do with python or R?

Comment: Do you want to stop after printing the first match? With 3 keywords to look for, what is a match? any one of the 3 keywords ? when all three are found on the line?

Comment: OP might want to learn a scripting language to perform tasks as requested above. That might explain the tag python previously?

Comment: what do you think `| head -1` does in your first command?

Comment: @karakfa , | head -1 will print the first occurrence of the string and the repeat string will be ignored.

Comment: @Nullman                                                                                                                           I have used R for this, but I could not extract the first occurrence. my R script printing all the rows where ever it finds the key word.                                                                       x = data.frame(read.csv("t3.csv"))                                                                            
y = grep("keyword1|keyword2|keyword3", x$Gene_Name.ID)                                                   z = x[y, ]

Comment: @Jayjargot                                                                                                                                   I have to print the first occurrence of all the three key words. I could print my first key word with first occurrence by above commands. But I have to print the first occurrence of all the three keywords.

Comment: @ZF007                                                                                                                                               I am a biologist and beginner to scripting languages. Therefore, Please help me to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is needed to introduce variables to only print one line which contains a keyword.

The situation where more than one keyword is found on a line, should be taken into account as well.

Give a try to this:

```
awk '$0 ~ keyword1 "|" keyword2 "|" keyword3 {
  if ($0 ~ keyword1 && k1 == 0) { tbp=1; k1=1 }
  if ($0 ~ keyword2 && k2 == 0) { tbp=1; k2=1 }
  if ($0 ~ keyword3 && k3 == 0) { tbp=1; k3=1 }
  if (tbp == 1) { print ; tbp=0 }
  if ( k1+k2+k3 >= 3 ) exit
}' keyword1=" my key " keyword2="car" keyword3="bathroom" ./filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-m1` option of grep to stop on the first occurrence.
Eg :

```
 grep -E -m1 'string1|string2' your_file
```

Comment: Dear funkyjelly,                                                                                                                                  its not working, its printing only one string with the first occurence, but its not printing the second string.